# Inserir em campo no mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

Tenho um sistema onde tem partidas cadastradas e o usuário logado tenta acertar os resultados dessas partidas, Cada partida tem um id de cadastro que está com o nome (jogo) no banco de dados, já tenho um if e else caso ele acerte ou erre o placar, porém eu não consigo fazer com que caso ele acerte ou erre insira no banco no campo resultado se ele Ganhou ou Perdeu, já tentei com um UPDATE dentro do if e else porém quando dou um UPDATE ele está atualizando todos os resultados, tipo ele joga Vitoria para todas as apostas. Segue o código de aposta...

apostar.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../conn/conexao.php");
if(!empty($_SESSION['email'])){

}else{
   echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Aréa Restrita.');
   window.location.href='/bolao/index.php';</script>";
}

$nome=$_SESSION['nome'];
$email=$_SESSION['email'];
$saldo="SELECT * FROM tb_usuario WHERE email= '$email'";
$exe= mysqli_query($conexao, $saldo);
$linha = mysqli_fetch_array($exe);

$btnApostar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnApostar', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnApostar){
   include_once ("../conn/conexao.php");
   $dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

   $aposta = "INSERT INTO tb_aposta(apostacasa, apostafora, valor, data, usuario, jogo)VALUES(
   '".$dados['apostacasa']."',
   '".$dados['apostafora']."',
   '".$dados['valor']."',
   '".$dados['data']."',
   '".$_SESSION['email']."',
   '".$dados['jogo']."'
   )";
   $r_aposta = mysqli_query($conexao, $aposta) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
   $verificacao = "SELECT * FROM  tb_jogos WHERE jogo=".$dados['jogo'];
   $exe= mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conexao, $verificacao));
   $email=$_SESSION['email'];
   $saldo=$linha['saldo'];
   $valor=$_POST['valor'];
   // var_dump($exe);
   if (($valor) > ($saldo)){
      echo
      "<script>
      alert('Voce nao possui saldo para realizar a aposta.')
      window.location = 'apostar.php';
      </script>";
   }else{

      if(($dados['apostacasa'] == $exe['placarcasa']) && ($dados['apostafora'] == $exe['placarfora'])){

         $up = mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE tb_usuario SET saldo=saldo+'$valor' WHERE email = '$email' ")or die (mysqli_error($conexao));

         echo "<script> alert('Voce acertou, parabéns')
         window.location.href='apostar.php';
         </script>";

      }else{ //se estiver errado irá diminuir o valor apostado

         $up = mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE tb_usuario SET saldo=saldo-'$valor' WHERE email = '$email' ")or die (mysqli_error($conexao));

         echo "<script> alert('Voce errou, tente outra partida')
         window.location.href='apostar.php';
         </script>";
      }
   }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
   <!-- As 3 meta tags acima *devem* vir em primeiro lugar dentro do `head`; qualquer outro conteúdo deve vir *após* essas tags -->
   <title>Lance Web</title>
   <!-- Bootstrap -->
   <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <!-- HTML5 shim e Respond.js para suporte no IE8 de elementos HTML5 e media queries -->
   <!-- ALERTA: Respond.js não funciona se você visualizar uma página file:// -->
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
   <style type="text/css">
   /*Aqui deixa a imagem de fundo responsiva*/
   body{ 
      background: url(../img/principal.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
   }

   #font{
      color:white;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
   }

   .img-responsive {
      max-width:250px;
      max-height:150px;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
   }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- nav e o menu -->   
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Aqui e como ira aparece em um telefone -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <!-- Aqui no span, são os 3 pontos ao abrir em um telefone -->
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Voltar</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Aqui se edita a parte do saldo -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a>Saldo&nbsp; R$<?php echo $linha['saldo']; ?><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="apostar.php">Apostar<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="historico.php">Histórico<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="ranking.php">Ranking<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="loja/loja.php">Loja<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         <!-- Aqui se edita a parte do sair -->  
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="sair.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></a></li>
         </ul>

      </div><!-- fim da div collapse, ela faz com que abra um menu ao aumentar o site -->
   </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

<?php
include("../conn/conexao.php");
//ORDER BY serve para organizar os dados de acordo com o que voce quiser
$buscar="SELECT *, a.jogo as id_jogo FROM tb_jogos a LEFT JOIN tb_aposta b ON (a.jogo = b.jogo) GROUP BY id_jogo ORDER BY id_jogo DESC";
$exe= mysqli_query($conexao, $buscar) or die ("OCORREU UM ERRO AO MOSTRAR OS DADOS");
//começo da tabela
echo "<br><br><div class='container'>
<table class='table table-inverse'>
<thead>
<tr bgcolor='#222222' align='center'>
<th><font color='white'>Codigo Partida</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Time Casa</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Placar</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Time Fora</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Placar</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Lance</font></th>
<th><font color='white'></font></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</div>";


while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($exe)){
   $desativa_btn = "type='submit'";
   if($linha['usuario'] == $_SESSION['email']){
      $desativa_btn = "disabled='disabled' type='button'";
   }
   echo "<form class='form-group' action='' method='post'>
   <input class='form-control' type='hidden' name='data' id='id_01' readonly>
   <tbody>
   <tr bgcolor='#222222'>
   <td><font color='white'><input type='int' class='form-control' name='jogo' maxlength='1' value=".$linha['id_jogo']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly'></font></td>
   <td><font color='white'>".$linha['casa']."</font></td>
   <td><input type='int' class='form-control' name='apostacasa' maxlength='1' value='' style='text-align: center;'></td>
   <td><font color='white'>".$linha['fora']."</font></td>
   <td><input type='int' class='form-control' name='apostafora' maxlength='1' value='' style='text-align: center;'></td>
   <td><input type='int' class='form-control' name='valor' maxlength='5' value='' style='text-align: center;'></td>
   <td><input ".$desativa_btn." class='btn btn-success submit-botao' type='submit' value='Apostar' name='btnApostar'></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </form>";
}
?>

<script> // script da data atual...
var today = new Date();
var dy = today.getDate();
var mt = today.getMonth()+1;
var yr = today.getFullYear();
document.getElementById('id_01').value= yr+"-"+mt+"-"+dy;
</script>

<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vc quer "inserir" ou "atualizar"?

Comment: Deve estar faltando um AND na clausula WHERE do update. Como é a tabela `tb_usuario`?

Comment: Não vai ser na tabela tb_usuario vai ser em outra tabela tb_aposta que possui um campo resultado, e a mesma tabela em que insiro os dados da aposta...

Comment: @DvD vai ser inserido no caso... porém eu já faço um insert nessa tabela no mesmo código

Comment: Na pergunta vc diz que quer fazer um UPDATE. Qual é o certo?

Comment: Na pergunta só tem 2 UPDATES e são na tabela `tb_usuario`. Vou invocar meus poderes mágicos para adivinhar o erro no seu código :)

Comment: Séria um UPDATE porém o campo Resultado não está na tb_usuario está na tb_aposta, a tb_usuario tem o saldo do usuário e cada acerto o usuário recebe o valor apostado por isso tem o UPDATE na tb_usuario, o que eu preciso e que seja feito um UPDATE em mais uma tabela que é a tb_aposta no campo resultado que irá receber vitoria caso acerte ou derrota caso erre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque no `if...else` onde você está atualizando o saldo, a query referente ao `UPDATE` quando o jogador acerta ou erra, respectivamente:

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE tb_aposta SET resultado='vitoria' WHERE usuario = '$email' AND jogo = '$dados['jogo']'")or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
```

e

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE tb_aposta SET resultado='derrota' WHERE usuario = '$email' AND jogo = '$dados['jogo']'")or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
```

O `if` ficaria assim:

```
if (($valor) > ($saldo)){
   echo
   "<script>
   alert('Voce nao possui saldo para realizar a aposta.')
   window.location = 'apostar.php';
   </script>";
}else{

   if(($dados['apostacasa'] == $exe['placarcasa']) && ($dados['apostafora'] == $exe['placarfora'])){

      $up = mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE tb_usuario SET saldo=saldo+'$valor' WHERE email = '$email' ")or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
      mysqli_query("UPDATE tb_aposta SET resultado='vitoria' WHERE usuario = '$email' AND jogo = '$dados['jogo']'")or die (mysqli_error($conexao));

      echo "<script> alert('Voce acertou, parabéns')
      window.location.href='apostar.php';
      </script>";

   }else{ //se estiver errado irá diminuir o valor apostado

      $up = mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE tb_usuario SET saldo=saldo-'$valor' WHERE email = '$email' ")or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
      mysqli_query("UPDATE tb_aposta SET resultado='derrota' WHERE usuario = '$email' AND jogo = '$dados['jogo']'")or die (mysqli_error($conexao));

      echo "<script> alert('Voce errou, tente outra partida')
      window.location.href='apostar.php';
      </script>";
   }
}
```

> **Sugestão:**
>
> Em vez de usar "vitoria" e "derrota" como valores, tente usar `1` para
>   "vitoria" e `0` para "derrota", para deixar seu banco mais enxuto, e
>   acho melhor para trabalhar.